# Python : how to organize properties (constants)?

Tags: python

I am using Python and I need to read some environment constants for my application (e.g. urls, database urls, client_id, client_secret, etc.), depending on the deployment platform (DEV, PRODUCTION).

In Java I used to store them in properties file, I wonder what is the best way to store these constants ? Should I create a separate file or create a dictionary directly in my file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer this :

https://martin-thoma.com/configuration-files-in-python/

There are multiple ways to store configurations in python.

Also you can have separate config.py :

https://github.com/realpython/flask-by-example/blob/master/config.py.

For your requrement :
The python file: `PythonPropertyReader.py`

```
import ConfigParser
config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
config.read('ConfigFile.properties')

print config.get('URLSection', 'url.1')
print config.get('URLSection', 'url.2')
```

The property file: `ConfigFile.properties`

```
[URLSection]
url.1=asd.com
url.2=ghj.com
```

Also you can use urls property comma seperated and split it in the reader.

For more functionality, read: https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html

Comment: hi, thank you for the site ! I also want to store a list of constant API url which will be called by a program, what do you recommend to use in this case ?

Comment: I edited the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this

```
# config.py
import os

class Config:
    APP_URL = os.environ.get['APP_URL']
    DB_CONNECTION_STRING = os.environ.get['DB_CONNECTION_STRING']
```

Then import the config file in the app.py file.